# How to get the smallest number of an array with the exception of sentinel value?

Tags: java

I made a code, my only problem is that it displays the sentinel value (zero) as its smallest number.

How do I ignore the sentinel value when taking the smallest number?

```
for (int c = 0; c < lengthOfArray; c++) {
    if(arr[c] < min)
        min = arr[c];             
             
    if (arr[c] > max)
       max = arr[c];      
}
             
System.out.println("Smallest:");
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println("Largest:");
System.out.println(max);
```

Below is my expected output:

```
(input:)
1 5 3 0

(output:)
Smallest:
 1
Largest:
5
```

However, my current code would always display 0 (zero) in the Smallest.

Comment: Please share an input example and the expected output

Comment: `arr[c] < min` will be true when you want to update `min`. Can you imagine how you could add to that expression to be false if `arr[c]` is the sentinel value?

Comment: Inside the first if statement add `&& arr[c] !=0`

Comment: also provide a sample array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

You may add a condition on the value along woth `min` one :

```
if (arr[c] < min && arr[c] != 0)
```

---

#### Improve

You can iterate on values and not in index, code may be nicer :

```
int[] arr = new int[]{8, 6, 9, 0, 6, 8};
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int val : arr) {
    if (val < min && val != 0)
        min = val;
    if (val > max)
        max = val;
}

System.out.println("Smallest: " + min); // Smallest: 6
System.out.println("Largest:" + max); // Largest:9
```

Answer (score 1):

just add an condition

```
for (int c = 0; c < lengthOfArray; c++) {
  if(arr[c] != 0){

    if(arr[c] < min)
        min = arr[c];             
             
    if (arr[c] > max)
       max = arr[c];  

   }
}
             
System.out.println("Smallest:");
System.out.println(min);
System.out.println("Largest:");
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach for solve your problem:

```java
IntSummaryStatistics arrSummaryStatistics = IntStream.of(arr).summaryStatistics();

System.out.println("Smallest:");
System.out.println(arrSummaryStatistics.getMin());
System.out.println("Largest:");
System.out.println(arrSummaryStatistics.getMax());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant using [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html):

```
int[] nums = {1, 5, 3, 0};
OptionalInt min = IntStream.of(nums).filter(x -> x != 0).min();
OptionalInt max = IntStream.of(nums).filter(x -> x != 0).max();
```